# Which HTTP status code when missing client credentials for 3rd party service?

Tags: spring-boot, http, authentication, http-status-codes

I am building an internal service Spring Boot application that provides a single API for various different services behind it.

My application can call various other API's on behalf of a user (i.e. execute a query), providing a single, clearly defined homogeneous interface.

My application has it's own standard authentication. Any failure will lead to a 401 UNAUTHORIZED with an empty body. Additionally, some of these APIs require credentials that my users can provide to my application. (it is an internal application. My users and I are aware of the security impact of managing '3rd-party' credentials).

Now I am looking for the right HTTP status code in the 400-range to return when a user is authenticated correctly with my application, but I am missing the required credentials to be able to complete the request to the remote API on behalf of the user.

I had a few options:

- 401 UNAUTHORIZED - Seems to fit best, but I don't like re-using the same HTTP status code I use for authentication failures of my application as well. I would need to add a body and message to distinguish between the 2.
- 407 PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED - Seems semantically fitting, since my application acts as a proxy, but is very off-standard and I won't be able to comply with the specs to send proxy authentication information headers. Also, it is the other way around. The proxy (my app) is fine, the service behind it needs authentication.
- 412 PRECONDITION_FAILED - Preconditions are not meant for application logic
- 428 PRECONDITION_REQUIRED - Same as above.

What would be a good HTTP status code to return in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If the client is not sending the 3rd party credentials to the service and the server itself is managing the credentials, you should look in the 500 range.

400 series HTTP codes are for client misconfiguration or error with content.

500 series HTTP codes indicate a problem with the server's operation.

In the case you have described, I believe you have indicated that the server is configured with the credentials. While the server may receive a 400 series code while making the request on behalf of the client, the client's request, hopefully syntactically valid, the server should respond with a 500 series code indicating it could not process the request and provide an appropriate code.

Comment: Interesting suggestion! Even if it is the responsibility of the client to first provide his/her credentials to my service, I should still respond with a 500 if the client failed to do so? To me, a 500 seems like something a client can't 'fix', yet in this case they could by first sending the credentials in a separate request.

Comment: Think if it this way, if in another request the client configured the credentials, then in a subsequent request the server utilized the credentials and failed, you would still want to send back a 500 series code as the server is misconfigured outside the scope of the current request. Simple way of thinking 1xx hold on, 2xx here ya go, 3xx go over there, 4xx you screwed up, 5xx I screwed up